# propositional logic simplification rules

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

$p\land (q\lor \lnot r)\lor(\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r)$

how do I solve this? Can I just combine $(q\lor \lnot r)\lor(\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r)$?

Comment: The expression is of the form $p\land A\lor B$, which is ambiguous.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? Do you need a truth value?
Also as Arthur mentioned, you need to put additional parentheses. Your expression could either be: $ 
p∧((q∨∼r)∨(∼p∨∼q∨r))$ or $
(p∧(q∨∼r))∨(∼p∨∼q∨r)$